# How to download Xcode documentation? (on windows)

Tags: macos, mac, iphone, download, xcode

Xcode Documentation only downloads to the current computer from within Xcode. I want to download the iPhone OS 3.0 Reference Library but the thing is - I am not using my Mac right now. My Mac is at my home and doesn't have internet connection.

I don't know how it would be possible?

Comment: I want something like this. this link gives the idea how we can download offline xcode3 docs.

http://learning2code.blogspot.com/2008/05/download-xcode-docsets-to-your-hard.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Stack Overflow there is a very similar question on how to obtain the Xcode Documentation as well: [Question 1384622](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384622/xcode-3-2-offline-documentation)

In order to download the documentation (which is compressed in an `xar` archive) you need to determine where the appropriate files are stored; in this case the appropriate feed is at < http://developer.apple.com/rss/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_1.atom > This can be found by clicking on the `i` symbol beside the entry in the Documentation section of Xcode's Preferences. You will need to use `curl` or `wget` to read the `.atom` file as Safari won't show the details.

The necessary file needed to be download is http://devimages.apple.com/docsets/Oct2009/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiPhone3_1.iPhoneLibrary.xar

Then you can follow the instructions from [learning2code](http://learning2code.blogspot.com/2008/05/download-xcode-docsets-to-your-hard.html)

Once you've copied the .xar file to your Mac (It's about 125MB) you need to install it:

1. Move the .xar file to `/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/` and extract the file by running `xar -xf on the file from the same directory. (Run`cd /Developer/Documentation/DocSets` first).
2. You then need to change the permissions on the files by running `sudo chown -R -P _devdocs *.docset`
3. Launch Xcode and you should be good to go.

Comment: "I am not using my Mac right now" - ie, he wants the documentation on Windows.

Comment: Is it necessary? /Developer/Documentation/DocSets/ .. can't we extract somewhere else?

Comment: Yes - Dave DeLong is commenting right. I am on windows. Mac is at my home & office pc is connected to internet.

Comment: @sagar: You don't need to extract to `/Developer/Documentation/DocSets/` but this is the default location for Documentation. You can change that path to wherever you want *but* Xcode will be looking at that location for the Documentation if you want it to appear in Xcode.

Comment: @Dave: From what I understood he needed to download the documentation on his PC so he could load it on his Mac. The documentation is just HTML so a program that will extract the files from the .xar archive would work and can be extracted using 7zip.